# Can this be stretched without an actual stretching?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there any way to make this picture in 1920x1080? Both sides are filled with a lot of pencil strokes and for me, this makes it nearly impossible to use even a stamp and duplicate a part of the background to fill the rest of the white sides.

[image]

Comment: how is this question different from your previous one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Photoshop's Content-aware Fill can do a reasonable job of that, these days.

I think the version I'm using is fairly new in CC2019, & now has its own menu item & edit page.

First, select the white areas with the magic wand [use antialias & contiguous, but *don't feather the selection afterwards* *]
Then from Edit menu > Content-aware Fill...

[image]

This was done simply with the default parameters, which gives...

[image]

*I've long noticed that Content-Aware Fill just doesn't like the edges to be feathered. It can make a complete mess of the job if you do, though it's somewhat counter-intuitive - somehow you'd expect that a little smoothing over the edges would help. It doesn't.
Quick example with feathered edges -

[image]

*After comments:*
I'd try smoothing the join with the spot heal brush after merging the layers.
But bear in mind I was working from a crop taken from a screenshot [& still didn't actually see it until I zoomed in a fair way] - you ought to get far better results from the original.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any possibilities of getting rid of these annoying marks/lines lef after using Content-aware fill?

Comment: You'd have to tell us which particular ones you consider 'annoying'. I thought it did a reasonable job; far better than it would have done a year or two ago.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/1b43965d290dd36f7d0c955fe668ab4f
I marked it on the screenshot above.

Comment: I'd go with spot heal; merge the layers first. [tbh, I hadn't looked close enough to see the join]

Comment: Yeah... it left even bigger marks... Nevermind I used the Blur Tool and it looks better now, thank you.
https://gyazo.com/7925e349d2b283e56bc939a6228ab744